# How do you phrase XXX number of people have Internet addiction in Chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar

I have a phrase： XXX number of people are addicted to the Internet.

I wrote this as: xxx 个人有（InternetAddiction.

Or could I use the phrase 上瘾用网络?

However I am not sure if it is correct grammatically.

XXX 个人上瘾用网络.

Comment: more possibilities at jukuu: besides 上了瘾  among 1st 20 of 100 samples for "addicted to": find :对...入了迷,沉迷于... (television,video games)

Answer (score 3):

A more formal form to say it:

> 幾千萬人有互聯網[依存症](https://tw.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20050409000010KK06451) - 'ten of millions of people have Internet Addiction'

A more colloquial way to say it:

> 幾千萬人上網成癮 - 'ten of millions of people getting online so much it became an addiction to them'
>
> or simply
>
> 幾千萬人有上網癮 - 'ten of millions of people have internet addiction'

Answer (score 1):

XXX number of people are addicted to the Internet

XXX 个人上网成瘾.

Answer (score 0):

沉迷(于) is the term I heard most in medias. For example, 成千上万人沉迷于网络. 成千上万人沉迷于网游。成千上万人沉迷于手游。

Comment: see comment  #1..

Comment: @user6065, I saw it. But I'd like to weigh in more on his usage, like by whom, how often it's been used, and attaching more examples.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "xxx个人对网络上瘾".

In this situation, people are addicated to internet, but not use internet to addicate. Actually, "xxx个人上瘾用网络" is just like "xxx number of people are addicted use internet", which is a broken sentence.